# How to train Spacy3 project with FP16 mixed precision

Tags: nlp, pytorch, spacy, huggingface-transformers, spacy-3

**The goal is to run `python -m spacy train` with FP16 mixed precision** to enable the use of large transformers (`roberta-large`, `albert-large`, etc.) in limited VRAM (RTX 2080ti 11 GB).

The new Spacy3 [project.yml approach](https://spacy.io/usage/projects#project-yml) to training directly uses [Huggingface-transformers models](https://huggingface.co/models?filter=pytorch) loaded via [Spacy-transformers v1.0](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers). Huggingface models can be run with mixed precision just by adding the `--fp16` flag ([as described here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/examples.html#distributed-training-and-mixed-precision)).

The spacy config was generated using `python -m spacy init config --lang en --pipeline ner --optimize efficiency --gpu -F default.cfg`, and checked to be complete by `python -m spacy init fill-config default.cfg config.cfg --diff`. Yet no FP16 / mixed-precision is to be found.

#### To reproduce

Use the [spaCy Project: Named Entity Recognition (WikiNER)](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines/ner_wikiner) with changed `init-config` in `project.yml` to use a GPU and a transformer (`roberta-base` by default):

```yaml
commands:
  -
    name: init-config
    help: "Generate a transformer English NER config"
    script:
      - "python -m spacy init config --lang en --pipeline ner --gpu -F --optimize efficiency -C configs/${vars.config}.cfg"
```

#### What was tested

- Added `--fp16` to `python -m spacy project run`
- Added `--fp16` to `python -m spacy train`
- Added `fp16 = true` to `default.cfg` in various sections (`[components.transformer], [components.transformer.model], [training], [initialize]`)

The logic was `transformers` are run in FP16 as such:

```py
from transformers import TrainingArguments
TrainingArguments(..., fp16=True, ...)
```

#### SW stack specifics

```sh
 - spacy              3.0.3
 - spacy-transformers 1.0.1
 - transformers       4.2.2
 - torch              1.6.0+cu101
```